# Need to configure generic SAML 2.0 with springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have created spring boot application and added SAML but I have to configure generic SAML in spring boot after running my application. Is there any way to add configuration for SSO after running spring boot application.

we are expecting to set up a system where user can dynamically set there SAML configuration without restarting system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

If you have to configure generic SAML in spring boot in runtime. You have to implements **org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository** and **java.lang.Iterable**(Same as **InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository**)

In InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository ther is one HashMap
**private final Map<String, RelyingPartyRegistration> byRegistrationId;** .
You have to make this map public and put new **RelyingPartyRegistration** in this map. Make sure that key of **byRegistrationId** is same while putting new RelyingPartyRegistration in Map.

```
public class CustomRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository implements RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository, Iterable<RelyingPartyRegistration> {

    private Map<String, RelyingPartyRegistration> byRegistrationId = new HashMap<>();

    public CustomRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(SsoConfigService ssoConfigService) {
        RelyingPartyRegistration relyingParty = ssoConfigService.getRelyingPartyRegistration(); // need default SAML RelyingPartyRegistration to start application 
        setByRegistrationId(relyingParty);
    }

    @Override
    public RelyingPartyRegistration findByRegistrationId(String registrationId) {
        return this.byRegistrationId.get(registrationId);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<RelyingPartyRegistration> iterator() {
        return this.byRegistrationId.values().iterator();
    }

    public void setByRegistrationId(RelyingPartyRegistration relyingPartyRegistration) {
        byRegistrationId.put("saml", relyingPartyRegistration);
    }
}
```